# JQuery update javascript snippet

Tags: jquery

The scenario is that I'd like to update a javascript snippet (that renders a widget) when a user clicks a button.

The idea is that a user can enter a number of parameters to configure their widget and then click a button to see a preview of it.

Is there a way to do this via jquery?

The snippet would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var yoc_w_frame = "SiteName";
var yoc_home = "HomePath";
var yoc_w_width = 300;
var yoc_w_height = 250;
//--><script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/js/js.js"></script>
```

I tried `$("#divTest").append( script );` where script is a var that holds the built up script string.

Comment: Are you trying to update the snippet directly in the file itself or are you just looking for a preview that won't be (but could be) saved?

Comment: To update the snippet directly.  For more context, I also have a text box that I update with latest javascript, (updated with users latest preference changes).  The flow is that a user selects their preferences, and then clicks "update" at which time I'd like to (1) show them the code in the textbox that they should cut and paste and (2) I'd like to write that same code to the page so that they can see the latest preview of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to to do it like this (some ugly code follows):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         var i = 0;

         function update() {
            i++; 
            var script = '<script type="text/javascript"> function test() { alert(' + i + ');}<\/script>';
            $(script).appendTo(document.body);
            test();
         }
       </script>

       <a href="javascript:update()">click</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.

This does work, however, there is something different about trying to write the script tag with the src attr:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/js/js.js"></script>

from my example above, this is actually the piece that does the rendering.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have, and could get the widget to render at the bottom of the page, but didn't have any luck getting it to render by appending it to a div, (for placement).  I'll have to read more about the $.getScript() method and how to works.